# How do I extract a string from another string php

Tags: php, string, substr

I'd like to extract a string from another string but the only thing I could see was substr() which uses integers when my strings will be different lengths.

Take a look at the string, I have a bunch of these I want to extract and echo the extras only if they exist. How can I do this with PHP. Thanks guys.

```
$string = 'Apple iPhone 6 Plus (Refurbished 16GB Silver) on EE Regular 2GB (24 Month(s) contract) with UNLIMITED mins; UNLIMITED texts; 2000MB of 4G data. £37.49 a month. Extras: Sennheiser CX 2.00i (Black)';

function freegifts($string) {
   if (strpos($string, 'Extras:') !== false {

        extract extras...

   }
}
```

So the function at the moment just checks to see if the word 'Extras:' is present, in this case i'd just like to echo 'Sennheiser CX 2.00i (Black)'

Comment: would be best to use regular expressions here. (?<=Extras:).*

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand?

Comment: could you return strpos to a string and then just use substr with a start of 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a regular expression is a fine idea, an alternative is plain old explode:

```
$string = 'Apple iPhone 6 Plus (Refurbished 16GB Silver) on EE Regular 2GB (24 Month(s) contract) with UNLIMITED mins; UNLIMITED texts; 2000MB of 4G data. £37.49 a month. Extras: Sennheiser CX 2.00i (Black)';

    $x=explode('Extras:',$string);

    if(!empty($x[1])){
    echo    $x[1];
    }
```

output "Sennheiser CX 2.00i (Black)"

Comment: This works, I've never used explode before thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (preg_match("(?<=Extras:).*", $string, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

Comment: i'd like to echo what was found

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'Apple iPhone 6 Plus (Refurbished 16GB Silver) on EE Regular 2GB (24 Month(s) contract) with UNLIMITED mins; UNLIMITED texts; 2000MB of 4G data. £37.49 a month. Extras: Sennheiser CX 2.00i (Black)';

// 'Extras:' is 7 chars
$extras = substr($string, strpos($string, 'Extras:') + 7);

echo $extras;

OUTPUT: Sennheiser CX 2.00i (Black)
```

there is prob. an easier way to do this, but it works if you are always looking for what is after 'Extras:' strpos() returns an int.